# ORM with magic getters/setters

Tags: php, algorithm, reflection

I'm playing around with PHP, trying to write a small ORM. Having worked with Magento quite a bit lately, I've fallen in love with the automagic getters/setters that Magento, I think, inherited from Zend.

For those, who've never seen it in action, this is what I'm talking about:

> ```
> $my_object->setSomeProperty('foo');
> ```

just works, as does:

> ```
> $my_object->getSomeProperty();
> ```

which obviously yields "foo".

Since I'm trying to implement an ORM, my goal is to provide the user with the ability to use generic functions on one hand, where:

> ```
> $orm_object->setSomeProperty('foo'):
> ```

would map to:

> ```
> $orm_object->set('some_property', 'foo') // set() would obviously be a generic part of the ORM
> ```

by convention.

On the other hand, if the user wanted to handle some situations differently, he could do so by defining a more specifically named function.

> ```
> class foo extends ORM {
>     function setSome($arg_1, $arg_2)
>     {
>         …
>     }
> }
> ```

The above example call

> ```
> $orm_object->setSomeProperty('foo')
> ```

would now be mapped to

> ```
> $orm_object->setSome('property', 'foo')
> ```

instead of the default `set()`.

Do you have any feedback on my implementation?

```
function __call($name, $arguments) {
    if(preg_match('/([a-z]+)/', $name, $matches))
    {
        $action = $matches[0];
        if(preg_match_all('/([A-Z]+)([^A-Z]+)/', $name, $matches))
        {
            $matches = $matches[0];
            array_unshift(&$matches, $action);
            for ($i = count($matches); $i > 0; $i--)
            {
                $potential_func_name = implode('', array_slice($matches, 0, $i));
                if (method_exists($this, $potential_func_name))
                {
                    $arguments_rest = array_slice($matches, $i);
                    break; // found matching function! 
                }
            }

            // handle number of arguments now!
            $reflector = new ReflectionClass($this);
            $num_expected_params = count($reflector->getMethod($potential_func_name)->getParameters());

            $num_expected_params = $num_expected_params - count($arguments);

            $params = array();
            for ($i = $num_expected_params; $i > 1; $i--)
            {
                $params[] = strtolower(array_shift($arguments_rest));
            }

            $last_var = '';
            $i = 0;
            foreach($arguments_rest as $part)
            {
                $last_var .= strtolower($part);
                $i++;
                if ($i != count($arguments_rest)) $last_var .= '_';
            }

            $params[] = $last_var;

            if (count($arguments) == 1) {
                $arguments = array_shift(&$arguments);
            }

            $params[] = $arguments;

            return(call_user_func_array(array($this, $potential_func_name), $params));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are probably a lot of reasons I'm unaware of as a frontend guy to use this code, but I'm wondering why you would use this instead of existing PHP magic overloading? See http://php.net/language.oop5.overloading.php